# Store and access data on server using PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have a website that has the possibility to add comments which are just stored temporarily, when you reload the page the comments are gone. I save the comment data in an ObservAbleArrayList using knockout and javascript. One idea I had was to send this ObservAbleArrayList to my server, store it and then when the page is reloaded the stored arraylist would first update the commentfield. How could I do this with AJAX and PHP?

Here is my javascriptcode for the comments:

```
 function Comment() {
    var self = this;

    self.nickname = ko.observable();
    self.newMsg = ko.observable("");
    self.editable = ko.observable(false);

    self.addComment = function () {
       vm.comments.push(self);
       vm.selectedComment(new Comment());
    };

    self.deleteComment = function () {
        vm.comments.remove(self);
    };

    self.editComment = function () {
        self.editable(!self.editable());
    };
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.comments = ko.observableArray();
  self.selectedComment = ko.observable(new Comment());
}

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

Any help or examples would be very helpful! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the data as JSON to the server using jQuery as your bridge to handle the server side interaction with it's `$.ajax()` wrapper.

First, you need to mutate the data into a JSON object to be sent over and easily parsed. In knockout, you can use the `.toJSON(model)` method on a `ko` object to get the JSON interpretation of it, such as:

```
var jsonData = ko.toJSON(ViewModel);
```

Which will give you your JSON String. This is ready to be passed to the server, so now you can construct your `$.ajax()` call to your PHP script.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/my/script.ext',
    type: 'GET', //default anyway, provided for clarity
    dataType: 'json', //the returned data from the server will be automatically parsed as json
    data: jsonData, //the KO model we converted earlier
    success: function(data){
        //the server's response is in "data" above, jsonParsed already.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But to send my jsonData I would have to make a ajax function with type: 'POST' instead? 
Like this?

    self.sendEntry=function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"storage.php",
                data: jsonData
            });
        };

And then to retrieve it again I could use your GET method?

Comment: @Scatman_John You can use `POST` or `GET`, it doesn't matter. It's more about what's `semantically` correct. Are you posting data to the server? Or are you sending data to the server that will result in a response? If the former, `type: 'POST',` if the latter, `type: 'GET'`. Bear in mind, in PHP, the only change is `$_POST` as opposed to `$_GET`

Comment: Yes I was just thinking of posting the data to the server and then if the user refreshes the page all the old comments will still be there. So I guess when a comment is submitted I will use the POST and on pagerefresh a GET function will run.

Comment: @Scatman_John Correct! That is exactly how I'd handle it, too.

Comment: How does it work with the url file where I send the content, do I have to write a special PHP file that handles the transfer, and then it saves the content in a file?

Comment: @Scatman_John You would likely store this in the `$_SESSION` scope. :)

Comment: I want the comments to be stored permanently though, I don't think that's possible with $_SESSION, or am I wrong?